# How to construct a new vector/set of pointer from another vector/set of object?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, vector, set

### Background

I wanted to manipulate the copy of a vector, however doing a vector copy operation on each of its element is normally expensive operation.

There are concept called shallow copy which I read somewhere is the default copy constructor behavior. However I'm not sure why it doesn't work or at least I tried to do the copy of vector object and the result looks like a deep copy.

```
struct Vertex{
    int label;
    Vertex(int label):label(label){ }
};

int main(){
    vector<Vertex> vertices { Vertex(0), Vertex(1) };

    // I Couldn't force this to be vector<Vertex*>      
    vector<Vertex> myvertices(vertices); 

    myvertices[1].label = 123;

    std::cout << vertices[1].label << endl; 
    // OUTPUT: 1 (meaning object is deeply copied)

    return 0;
}
```

### Naive Solution: for pointer copy.

```
int main(){
    vector<Vertex> vertices { Vertex(0), Vertex(1) };

    vector<Vertex*> myvertices;
    for (auto it = vertices.begin(); it != vertices.end(); ++it){
        myvertices.push_back(&*it);
    }

    myvertices[1].label = 123;

    std::cout << vertices[1].label << endl;
    // OUTPUT: 123 (meaning object is not copied, just the pointer)

    return 0;
}
```

### Improvement

Is there any other better approach or `std::vector` API to construct a new vector containing **just the pointer** of each of the elements in the original vector?

Comment: You will not be manipulating a copy of the original vector if you use `myvertices`, you will be changing the original, are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: why don't you just manipulate the elements through `vertices`? I don't get your problem.

Comment: Because i'm performing an algorithm which requires me to remove vertices one by one, and it should be reseted again for another test cases.

Comment: still not clear, post a full example on what you want to do with both of those vectors

Comment: If you don't want to alter the original `std::vector` then you're just going to have to make a deep copy as your first code snippet shows.

Comment: There's no magic spell, if you want to alter variable's value and then reset it to its initial value you have to store the initial value somewhere (i.e., You need to keep a copy of the vector with the initial values).

Comment: I don't want to have a deep copy. I want to ensure the operation is very efficient, as in Just copy the pointer of all the elements in another vector.

Comment: Why not just maintain a pointer to the other vector? i.e. `std::vector<Vertex>* myvertices = &vertices;`

Comment: Let the `vertices` hold the original copy of the `Vertex`. Whereas `myvertices` is a list of pointer where i can simply remove each of the pointer when it doesn't satisfy certain condition

Comment: @Yeo Those pointers however will still point to the elements of the vector. If you alter an object through a pointer that it points to it, you still alter the initial object. In other words you'll still going to lose the initial values.

Comment: It doesn't matter, because I'm only interested in the existence of pointer of `myvertices`, because i'm going to erase these pointer one by one if they didn't meet any condition. And lastly to check `myvertices` is it empty or not.

Comment: @Yeo I think you should take a step back and think what exactly you're trying to achieve and then try to clearly formulate that and come back with that.

Comment: What do you mean by erasing a pointer? You can't delete pointers that their memory is not acquired by new etc.

Comment: @101010 well, since myvertices is full of pointer, we can simply erase it via `std::erase()`

Comment: So do you care about preserving the initial contents of `vertices` or not? If yes then deep copy is the only option, if no then you can go ahead and use the pointer copy. But with that said if the latter is the case then I don't see why you can't do your calculations via `vertices` in the first place.

Comment: @Yeo Sorry Now I got it, you simply want to hold an inventory of the elements in the original vector and then use `std::vector<T>::erase()` to erase any unwanted element from the inventory.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury yes, I don't care on preserving the content. I am solely using the pointer as book keeping to perform a very expensive algorithm

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Why do you think you want a shallow copy? You say you want to erase values that don't meet a condition, so why not do a conditional copy?  What about doing a partition and using iterators?

Comment: @kfsone `copy_if` if i understand what you mean, is still copying the object, and I don't really care about the object inside `myvertices`, and i use the pointer existance only for keeping track whether there exists any pointer in `myvertices` after performing an expensive algorithm

Comment: @kfsone, in my case, I'm not erasing the object, but rather erasing the pointer of the newly created `myvertices`

Comment: @101010 Thank you, you finally understood my problem. I'm not sure in what makes this question a bad question,. Although I find that it is clear enough for everyone....

Comment: @Yeo I think usage of expressions like `swallow copy`, `deep copy` is somewhat misleading.

Comment: @Yeo See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem. If you only care about the presence of values in a source vector, consider a bit mask solution instead of copying pointers.

Comment: @kfsone this is the first time i notice such problem in SO. (i learn from my mistake here) thank you. And also you give me another good idea for using bitmasking. I'll try for that approch first, it could possibly solve my problem better. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried boost's [ptr_vector](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html)? This way you always play with pointers and do not have to make copies.

Comment: @Sam I haven't use it, but i tried to avoid external library at the moment due to some constraint on my work environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could transform a vector of elements to a vector of pointers that point to the elements of the original vector that is better in terms of efficiency compared to your example, due to the fact that it preallocates the buffer of the vector of pointers, and IMHO more elegant is via using `std::transform` as follows:

```
std::vector<Vertex*> myvertices(vertices.size());
std::transform(vertices.begin(), vertices.end(), myvertices.begin(), [](Vertex &v) { return &v; });
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9cf6ed73c48088d2)

Or if you don't want to use a lambda for the unary operator:

```
std::vector<Vertex*> myvertices(vertices.size());
std::transform(vertices.begin(), vertices.end(), myvertices.begin(), std::addressof<Vertex>);
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/062b922e1c3f733d)

**Caution:** If you alter the original vector then you invalidate the pointers in the pointers' vector.

Comment: Yes, I want to erase from the newly created `myvertices` for the purpose of book keeping.

Comment: It's late so maybe I'm being stupid but this answer is essentially identical to the second code snippet in the question anyway, isn't it? Only just more elegant and perhaps slightly faster due to initial size allocation.

Comment: @101010, So, there is no constructor that can be used for my use cases?

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury Yes it gives a slightly better way to create the vector of pointers. I think that this is what the OP asks `Is there any other better approach or std::vector API to construct a new vector containing just the pointer of each of the elements in the original vector?`

Comment: With Boost iterator adaptors, you could reformulate this slightly as `auto vertexPtrs = vertices | boost::adaptors::transformed([](Vertex& v) { return &v; }); std::vector<Vertex*> myvertices(vertexPtrs.begin(), vertexPtrs.end());`

Comment: @Yeo -- I think you should really consider the **Caution** statement in the given answer.  You alter the vector, and all of those pointers that you've saved are not guaranteed to point to valid objects any more.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes, the original Vertex object insided `vertices` is fixed. The way I design the data structure such that the Vertex is only defined in one place, and this vertex is not modifiable, not addable, not deletable. Only pointer can be added or deleted, and it must happened in a different set or different vector.

Comment: @Yeo -- Are you referring to the `vector<Vertex>`?  That's what I'm referring to.  If that vector changes size (i.e. you add more points), then those pointers you stored in the `vector<Vertex*>` previously will be invalidated.

Comment: Yes, I'm refering to that `vector<Vertex> vertices`, as in the vector itself. sorry for the wrong wording earlier

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @kfsone for noticing on the main problem that it is very uncommon people wanted to keep track of pointer from another vector of object without utilizing the core idea behind it. He provided an alternative approach that solve similar problem by using bit masking. It may not be obvious for me at first until he mentioned that.

When we are trying to store **just the pointers** of another vector, we are most probably wanted to do some tracking, house keeping (keeping track) of another object. Which later to be performed on the pointer itself without touching the original data. For my case, I'm solving a minimum vertex cover problem via bruteforce approach. Whereby I will need to generate all permutation of vertices (e.g. 20 vertices will generate 2**20=1million++ permutation), then I trim down all irrelevant permutation by slowly iterating each of the vertices in the vertex cover and remove edges that are covered by the vertices. In doing so, my first intuition is to copy all pointers to ensure efficiency and later i could just remove the pointer one by one.

However, another way of looking into this problem is not to use vector/set at all, but rather just keep track each of those pointer as a bit pattern. I won't go in the detail but feel free to [learn from others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bit-manipulation).

The performance difference is very significant such that in bitwise, you can achieve O(1) constant time without much problem, whereas using a specific container, you tend to have to iterate each of the elements which bound your algorithm to O(n). To make it worst, if you are bruteforcing NP hard problem, you need to keep the constant factor as low as possible, and from O(1) to O(N) is a huge difference in such scenario.

Comment: I just noticed another problem with this approch. The approach is not always works for large data. The above answer is small (only 20 vertices or 20 bits). When encountering a large set of data, you will still have to track its pointer. Imagine under 20 bits you could perform left shift 20 bits, what if the problem given is above 10000. You couldn't possibly perform left shift 10000. That is far beyond the size of an `int` data type. Thus you still need a container and perform the O(N) operation for large data set.